# How do I add a "next slide" button in a CSS carousel while maintaining native scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have made a simple horizontal carousel and would like to add a button to 'jump to' each image/card. I'm pretty close with some jquery.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="p p1 active"></div>
<div class="p p2"></div>
<div class="p p3"></div>
</div>
<button class="next">NEXT</button>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.p {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(".next").click(function() {
  var $target = $('.p.active').next('.p');
  if ($target.length == 0)
    $target = $('.p:first');

  $('.wrap').animate({
    scrollLeft: $target.offset().left
  }, 'slow');

  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $target.addClass('active');
});
```

https://codepen.io/drewbots/pen/eYJzQQX

I *would* prefer vanilla Javascript for simplicity but working jquery would be fine. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I just noticed that the only thing missing from your code was adding `$('.wrap').scrollLeft()` to the animation. Just do that and it will have the same result as my code

Answer (score 0):

Use the offset method to obtain the position of the element in relation to the document and to scroll to the element use animate together with scrollLeft and scrollTop

```js
$(".next").click(function() {
  let offset
  let active = $('.active')
  let target = active.next()
  if(active.next()[0] == undefined) 
    target = $('.p').first()
    
  offset = target.offset()
  
  $('.wrap').animate({
      scrollLeft: $('.wrap').scrollLeft() + offset.left,
      scrollTop: $('.wrap').scrollTop() + offset.top
    })
  
  target.addClass('active')
  active.removeClass('active')
   
})
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.p {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
.p1 {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
.p2 {
  background-color: #E91E63;
}
.p3 {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="p p1 active"></div>
<div class="p p2"></div>
<div class="p p3"></div>
</div>
  <button class="next">NEXT</button>
```

Comment: I haven't explored ALL options, but can you suggest a way to wrap everything in a margin (e.g. body {margin:10px}), so that the cards stay "flush"? @Aks

Comment: As you asked for a suggestion, I would say that it might be interesting to group it in a flexible display in the form of a column or row, and from that you stylize it as you see fit

Comment: If I wrap everything in another div and add margin, this is the result: https://codepen.io/drewbots/pen/RwrRvMm. When you click NEXT, there is leftover margin from other slides. I'm trying to mess with the 100% width of the cards, e.g. width: calc (100% + 20px);, but this does not exactly work either. I'm going to keep at it, I'm so close! TY.

Comment: An alternative is to subtair 20 of `scrollLeft: $('.wrap').scrollLeft() + offset.left`

Comment: I think I got it. Add -20 to this line, like this: scrollLeft: $('.wrap').scrollLeft() + offset.left - 20, Thanks again!

Comment: Or use: `$('.p1')[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth'})`

Comment: You beat me to it

Comment: scrollIntoView is a pure js method, it does the automatic scroll function up to an element

Comment: `$('.wrap').scrollLeft() + offset.left - 20`, yes